# exporting non-numeric matrix from maple to matlab

Tags: matlab, maple

how can I export a non-numeric matrix from maple to Matlab? I tried to use this code:

```
ExportMatrix(matlabData, bb, target = MATLAB, format = rectangular, mode = ascii)
```

but I get this error:

`Error, (in ExportMatrix) Matrix contains non-numeric entries:  cannot export to Matlab`

Comment: I dont knwo how to do it, but do you know Matlab has MuPad, wich is the "same" software as Maple? maybe you can run you r code in Mupad instead of in Maple, and that may solve you a lot of problems! write mupad in the comand line

Comment: thank you so much but it's weird my Matlab hasn't MuPad! is it on R****b version of Matlab?

Comment: Oh, it may be...I think you need a separated license for that. Well, it was worth a try.

Comment: @Alexander1991: So if you type `mupad` in your command window nothing (or an error) comes up? MuPAD is included with the Symbolic Math toolbox I believe, which is standard on most installs unless you choose explicitly choose not to install it. You may also be able to export the matrix from Maple as text (something like `ExportMatrix("matrix.txt",M):`), read it in in Matlab (with some processing/formatting) and detect symbolic variables with `symvar` (or just specify the manually).

Comment: thank you so much `ExportMatrix("matrix.txt",M):` worked for me! btw actually yes when I type mupad in command windows it doesn't recognize the command and it said `Did you mean mad?`